# after postback my page shows different url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a form for inserting data. After postback of the form it shows different url for the form, but the page is same. I think the problem is created due to `return view('pages.booksin');` but I do not how to solve the problem.

controller code::

```
public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('pages.booksin');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $validatedInput = $request -> validate([
                'sel_bookID' => 'required',
                'NBilledDate' => 'required',  
                'NBilledNumber' => 'required',
                'NBilledQuantity' => 'required',
                'NBilledPrice' => 'required'
            ]);

            $ordered_books = new OrderedBook;
            $ordered_books -> BookID = $request->input('sel_bookID');
            $ordered_books -> BilledNum = $request->input('NBilledNumber');
            $ordered_books -> BilledDate = $request->input('NBilledDate');
            $ordered_books -> Qunatity = $request->input('NBilledQuantity');
            $ordered_books -> Price = $request->input('NBilledPrice');
            $ordered_books -> Remarks = $request->input('NBilledRemarks');    
            if($ordered_books->save())
            {
                Session::flash('alert-success', 'orderd successfully inserted');
            }    
            return view('pages.booksin');
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            Session::flash('alert-danger', $e->getMessage());
            return view('pages.booksin');
        }
    }
```

Route path set in `web.php` file

```
Route::resource('/order','OrderedBookController');
```

Initially, I open the page `booksin.blade.php` via , http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/create but after post back the shown url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/order. How should I solve this problem? Thank You!!!

Comment: try this:  return redirect()->back()->with('alert-success', 'orderd successfully inserted');

Comment: @SalmanZafar one simple question I close my xampp server then tried to insert in database hoping that it will be caught my exception but not. What I have done is `catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('alert-danger', $e->getMessage()); 
        }` I am getting all the error information. How can I print exception messages?

Comment: sorry i did'nt get your question mate

Comment: $e->getMessage();  is printing the exception message right ?